# Can I run 32-bit exe using ShellExecute API in 64-bit application?

Tags: winapi, 64-bit

Can I run 32-bit exe using `ShellExecute` API in 64-bit application?
Are there are potential pitfalls or problems with doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I run 32-bit exe using `ShellExecute` API in 64-bit application?

Yes you can. The only possible issue that you may encounter in this area is if you attempt to start a 64 bit process from a 32 bit process, and the executable, or the process working directory, are in a directory subject to the file system redirector. That is, the Windows system directory, `system32`.

In your case, from a 64 bit process, starting a 32 bit or 64 bit process presents no issues. Note that you really should use [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx) rather than [`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx), because the latter's error reporting is broken by design.